# Where to put logic - domain class vs. service class vs. other class?

Tags: java, spring

I'm developing a simple To-do app in Java using Spring framework. Now, I'm adding a feature which shows if a task is overdue. I'm not sure about where to put logic which checks if it is.

This is my To-do domain class:

```java
public class Todo {
    private Long id;
    private String body;
    private LocalDate doDate;

    // Constructors, getters and setters
}
```

This is my TodoService class:

```java
@Service
public class TodoService {
    @Autowired
    private TodoRepository todoRepository;

    public void save(Todo todo) { // ... }
    public void deleteById(Long id) { // ... }
    public Iterable<Todo> findAll() { // ... }    
    public Optional<Todo> findById(Long id) { // ... }
}
```

I'm thinking about 3 approaches:

1. Add a method *isOverdue()* to the domain class
2. Add a separate class OverdueChecker with a method *isOverdue(Todo todo)*
3. Add a method *isOverdue(Todo todo)* to my existing TodoService class

Which of these would be consider a good coding practice?

Comment: Do not **ever** do anything like 2 or 3. An object should expose meaningful behaviour, not just act like a dumb bag of data for other classes to work with.

Comment: 1 is fine. A signature of `isOverdue(LocalDate date)` might be more useful, and will be easier to test.

Comment: Should the Todo object know whether or not it is overdue intrinsically? Why does the service need to handle that if it it's a determinate state? If it does something else like track a system time, then the service makes sense, but if it's just using today's date, then the object itself can evaluate it.

Comment: @Michael I'm not judging in the context of this problem but the "never do 2" approach usually ends with classes having way too many responsibilities, hundreds of lines of code and being too hard to maintain. Don't be afraid to extract related responsibilities out of a class.

Comment: @ŁukaszNojek "Don't be afraid to extract related responsibilities out of a class"  obviously... but **never** in the form of treating an object like a stupid data holder with 10 getters and setters. Extract behaviour into, for example, composable decorators.

Comment: @Michael - currently `Todo` class has 3 fields, today it will gain a check for overdue, tomorrow ability to assigning to people, next commenting, labeling, filtering by category, assignment to projects, moving to folders, creating subtasks, and so on... So I'd refrain from saying *never* ;)

Comment: @ŁukaszNojek And with OP's approach you are suggesting the approach is `OverdueChecker`, `TodoPeopleAssigner`, `TodoCommenter`, `TodoLabeller`, `TodoCategoriser`, `TodoProjectAssigner`, `TodoFolderMover`, `TodoSubtaskCreator`

Comment: @Michael - No. I didn't say "do it always". I said "never say to never extract responsibilities" ;).

Comment: @ŁukaszNojek I'm sorry, but if these look like good classes to you, you are not doing OOP. The correct solution is: `LabeledTodo`, `AssignedTodo`, `CategorisedTodo` etc... A class should enscapsulate state and provide behaviour, **always**.

Comment: @ŁukaszNojek "never say to never extract responsibilities" I already said that extracting responsibilities is obviously good. The manner in which you are suggesting to extract the responsibilities is what's going to make for awful code.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the first solution since it's an easily determined state (I'm guessing you're just comparing doDate with doday's date) and that doesn't require a lot of logic behind it, if it did I would recommend using the service.
besides having something like `public boolean isOverdue(){...}` in the toDo class is cleaner